# How to put a computed observable as a cell data in Handsontable

Tags: knockout.js, handsontable

I have already integration of Handsontable with KnockoutJS here [http://jsfiddle.net/NHpEH](http://jsfiddle.net/NHpEH/).

```
     ko.bindingHandlers.handsontable = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor(); // TODO: what happens if value is null?         
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var colHeaders = allBindings.colHeaders() || true;
            var data = allBindings.handsontable();

            // TODO: make options customizable
            $(element).handsontable({
                data: data,
                minRows: value().length || 5,
                minCols: value()[0].length || 5,
                minSpareCols: 0,
                minSpareRows: 1,
                colHeaders: colHeaders,
                contextMenu: true,
                onChange: function (data, source) {
                    var headers = $(element).handsontable("getColHeader")
                    var tableData = $(element).handsontable("getData");

                    value(tableData);

                    allBindings.colHeaders(headers);
                }
            });

            $(element).handsontable("loadData", value());
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var colHeaders = allBindings.colHeaders();

            $(element).handsontable("updateSettings", {
                minRows: value().length,
                minCols: value()[0].length
            });
        }
    };
```

but I want to put a computed observable as a cell data in a cell. For example I want to show sum of two other cells in a cell.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, This is my solution. The code snippet is not optimized and is just a simple idea.

In this way, you can specify a computed observable for each specific cell. The third column is sum of the first three columns and the fourth column is multiply of them. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mortezasoft/Yr6KE/4/)

```
 function SumRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
     td.innerHTML = '<b>' + viewModel.SumForFirstRow() + '</b>';
     $(td).css({
         background: 'yellow'
     });
 }

 function MultiplyRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
     td.innerHTML = '<b>' + viewModel.MultiplyForFirstRow() + '</b>';
     $(td).css({
         background: 'pink'
     });
 }
 ko.bindingHandlers.handsontable = {
     init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
         var value = valueAccessor(); // TODO: what happens if value is null?         
         var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
         var colHeaders = allBindings.colHeaders() || true;

         var data = value();

         $(element).handsontable({
             data: data,
             minRows: value().length ? (value().length) : 5,
             minCols: value()[0].length || 5,
             minSpareCols: 0,
             minSpareRows: 0,
             colHeaders: colHeaders,
             contextMenu: false,
             onChange: function (data, source) {
                 var headers = $(element).handsontable("getColHeader")
                 var tableData = $(element).handsontable("getData");

                 value(tableData);

                 allBindings.colHeaders(headers);
             },
             cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                 if (row == 0) {
                     if (col === 3) {
                        return { type: { renderer: SumRowRenderer,readOnly: true}};
                     } else if (col === 4) {
                        return {type: {renderer: MultiplyRowRenderer,readOnly: true}};
                     }
                 }
             }
         });

     },
     update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
         var value = valueAccessor();
         var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
         var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
         var colHeaders = allBindings.colHeaders();

         $(element).handsontable("updateSettings", {
             minRows: value().length,
             minCols: value()[0].length
         });
     }
 };

 var viewModel = {
     data: ko.observableArray([

         [10, 10, 12, 0, 0]

     ]),
     colHeaders: ko.observableArray(["One", "Two", "Three", "Sum", "Multiply"])
 };

 viewModel.SumForFirstRow = ko.computed(function () {

     return parseInt(this.data()[0][0]) +
     parseInt(this.data()[0][1]) + 
     parseInt(this.data()[0][2]);

 }, viewModel);
 viewModel.MultiplyForFirstRow = ko.computed(function () {

     return parseInt(this.data()[0][0]) *
     parseInt(this.data()[0][1]) * 
     parseInt(this.data()[0][2]);

 }, viewModel);

 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add observables and a computed to your array:

```
var 2008Kia = ko.observable(10);
var 2008Nissan = ko.observable(11);
var 2008Toyota = ko.observable(12);
var 2008Honda = ko.observable(13);
var 2008Total = ko.computed(function() {
  return 2008Kia() + 2008Nissan() + 2008Toyota() + 2008Honda();
});

var data = ko.observableArray([
  ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda", "Total for Year"],
  ["2008", 2008Kia, 2008Nissan, 2008Toyota, 2008Honda, 2008Total],
  ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 15]
]);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/NHpEH/1/

Comment: Thanks man. I got your idea and tried to implement it in multiple ways but all my efforts failed. Of course I am new in both  Handsontable and Knockout. Could you pls give me a working example in jsfiddle?

Comment: So... why do you want to have a computed in there?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Fiddle Added, now using ko mapping plugin for flattening viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks again. As a matter of fact, I want to show an Excel like form to the specific customers in a business. Customers enter data in some cells and they can see some calculated data in other cells based on their inputs. That's why I want to put computed observables in some cells.
The problem with your snippet is that in the first time computed observable works but after that if you change any number in cells, Total number wont get updated. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: If that's what you want, then you'll need to create a custom renderer and a custom editor for handsonTable that knows how to work with observables.  See http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers_html.html for information in creating a custom renderer.  I would recommend using the custom renderer / editor to create elements inside a Handsontable with data-bind attributes (one per cell), then dynamically data-bind them to the appropriate viewmodel properties by calling `ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, newCellInHandsonTableWithDataBindAttribute);`

Comment: I had tried this already. There are two problems with this approach. 
First, custom renderer applies to all cells of a column, so we can have one computed observable for all cells in a column. Even if we pass the computed observable as a value to the custom renderer, It won't work.
Second problem is that what do you want to render inside the cells? span? input? <td data-bind='text:...'> ? none of them do not reflect the changes after first binding. 
If my explanations are not clear, pls let me know to implement it in fiddle and show you the result.